# Query to merge two tables based on some criteria

Tags: mysql

Table `users` includes columns `first`,`last`, and `company`.

Table `columns`contains 5 columns containing different information and a `company` column.

I was wondering if there is a way to select `users` record based on the criteria below AND select the row in the `columns` table that contains the same company name as he `comapany` column in the `users` table?

I appreciate any suggestions

Something like:

```
    $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users`,`columns` WHERE `first`=? AND `last`=? AND `users.company` = `columns.company`");
```

Comment: @Mihai That's not a very constructive comment. And just so you know, OP is using an implicit `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the companies are unique, you can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT [column list]
FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN `columns` c
    ON c.`company` = u.`company`
WHERE u.`first` = ?
    AND u.`last` = ?
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So how this works is, I am selecting `users` as table `u` combining it with `columns` table `c`, and based on the related column `company`, this constructs a result set and then I just use WHERE to narrow the rows? Also, why not use something like simply JOIN or INNER JOIN? why are we using LEFT join in this instance?

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` is used when there may not be a company for a particular user. You can try using a `JOIN` and see how it affects your result set. Otherwise, you're correct on how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There will never be an instance where the company field will be empty. Should I simply use `JOIN` in this case?

Comment: You can. You may want to enforce this rule using a foreign key.